# 180° phase difference alternator synchronisation

Tags: phase, synchronization

Consider two alternators with 180° phase difference in parallel feeding a purely resistive load. In my understanding, phase cancellation will occur. So, what happens to the power in the circuit?

Comment: consider the same two alternators, regardless of any load. What will happen to the alternators?

Comment: The power gets converted into smoke methinks.